# Get Sum of one column based on another column of another table in power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38dO3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DUKI.png)
I have to get the sum of the amount from Table A against all the phone numbers in Table b too. How do I do this in power bi? For a better understanding of my question, I am mentioning mysqli query too

Select count(phone) from tableA where date(dateCreated)>='2022-10-10' and date(dateCreated)<='2022-10-31' and phone IN(Select phone from tableB where is_mobile=0)

Need to get the sum of the amount from table A .

Comment: Select sample data from two tables and your expected output. Tell us the relation details between your two tables.

Comment: i mentioned the sample data here and the realtion is many to 1

Comment: You only provided samples from 1 table and in the image. Images are not the appropriate format of data to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Table B to have *distinct Tel. No* create relationship based on Tel. no from Table B to Table A

Create a calculated column in Table B and use

```
Amount = CALCULATE(SUMX('Table A','Table A'[Amount]))
```